# How can I host my website's root url ('/') on one hosting provider and every other url on another?

Tags: nginx, server, hosting, digital-ocean

So I have a domain(example.com), where I want the root url

```
example.com
```

to direct to my landing page's DNS that comes from its hosting provider and I want every other url

```
example.com/whatever-here
```

to direct to my main hosting provider, which is digital ocean with its DNS. I did it before, but with subdomains. The example.com part was directing to my landings and their hosts, while everything that started with the "app" subdomain (app.example.com) directed users to my main hosting. Now I want to do it without introduction of subdomains. Is it done somewhere on Nginx level? Or is it configured in my hosting providers' settings? Couldn't find the answer so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The hostname indicates what server your browser is going to connect to.  The requested path is then sent to that server, only after the browser has connected to it.

Comment: My question might be dumb, but can I host www.example.com on one and just example.com on another hosting? While I was transferring my website from one hosting to another, it worked like that for around a day. Then www.example.com stopped working altogether, while example.com works. Thank in advance.

Comment: Yes, `www.example.com` and `example.com` are two different hostnames and can point to different places.  Be aware that some questionable changes by Google Chrome developers hides the `www` in the address bar.  So, your setup may be confusing for users for a bit.  https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/google/google-chrome-hides-www-and-https-in-the-address-bar-again/

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Brad said, it's impossible to directly host a domain name on two different DNS'es simultaneously. However, I managed to find two approaches that don't do what I wanted, but the end result is pretty much the same:

1. Host www.domain.com on one server and domain.com on another. Not all providers support it, so it's a not guaranteed-to-work solution. But it's still a solution.
2. Use Nginx's proxy-pass without redirect or a similar function of your webserver.
   This way, you can have example.com actually load some-other-site.com without changing the browser url. I'll provide my Nginx configuration for reference:

```
location = / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://other-domain-or-ip.com/;
    }
```

This is just the result I wanted and it makes me think that I fell victim to the X->Y problem here.